# PocoCapsule project status

Tags: c++, open-source, spring, ioc-containers

Does anybody know the status of this C++ Inversion of Control Container?

Any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Last release was November 2009, but last activity on the code base was April 14, see http://code.google.com/p/pococapsule/updates/list.

There appears to be one author; contact him for detailed information about the status of the project.

Long periods between releases doesn't necessarily indicate a dead project.  Sometimes the code is so good, it doesn't need fixing every five minutes.  That it is open-source is good insurance; if you decide to use it, and there is a problem, you might be able to fix it yourself.